# SQL Join with one column in the joining table

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Q: There are two tables emp and dept having one column each i.e ID column

Tables are as

```
Emp Table        Dept Table 

ID                 ID  
1                  1 
1                  1  
2                  2
```

And join query is

```
Select * from emp e,dept d
where e.id = d.id?
```

and result of above join  is :

```
ID    ID
1      1
1      1
1      1
1      1
2      2
```

But I am not able to understand how this comes.
Can any one explain me this?

Answer (score 0):

A `join` repeats each row in the right hand table for each row in the left hand table, limited by the `on` clause.

So each row with `id = 1` is repeated twice, resulting in four rows with `id = 1`.

If you'd add another row with `id = 1` to both tables, you'd get `3 x 3 = 9` rows with `id = 1` in the result.